# $_POST field value gets altered after "init"

Tags: plugins, input

I'm new to wordpress development.

I'm trying to develop a simple plugin for practice. It involves a form submission from the frontend. The form has an input with the following code.

```
<input type='hidden' name='test' value='{"id": 1}'/>
```

When I submit the form, the value of 'test' field gets altered after the "init" hook.

My plugin code looks like the following

```
add_action('init', [$this, 'init']);

function init() {
    printe_r($_POST);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [test] => {\"id\":1}
)
```

The problem is that **json_decode** errors out. I have to use **stripslashes** like below to decode the json string.

```
json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['test']));
```

Is this behavior expected in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the expected behaviour. There's information on why it works like this here, and this function which can help in removing slashes from larger data structures: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/stripslashes_deep/

In the short term, if you can live without JSON for this field, why not just remove it, and if you need multiple hidden fields add them separately, e.g.:

```
<input type='hidden' name='testId' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='otherId' value='123'/>
```

And you can get those directly with:

```
echo $_POST['testId'];
echo $_POST['otherId'];
```

Will output:

```
1
123
```

Answer (score 0):

As @mozboz explained, WordPress is changing the values of `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, and `$_COOKIE`. If you need the raw values, use the function [`filter_input()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), and make sure to keep security concerns in mind.

Example:

```
$test = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'test', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```